# "Security update required" on Exchange account on Android 10 Beta

Tags: exchange, android-beta-program, android-10

I am on Android 10/Q Beta on Pixel 2 and my exchange email account stopped working and is constantly asking for security update. It doesn't lead me to anything when I click on it and hence stuck with no mail access. I've had Android 10 Beta for a few days now and the exchange account was working fine until now. Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same (Pixel 2 XL Q/Beta4) but there seems to be a workaround which works for me:

1. delete your Exchange account from Settings -> Accounts
2. delete the latest update from Gmail in Play Store
3. open Gmail and add your Exchange account
4. update your security settings when promted (should work here)
5. update gmail to the latest version

Comment: works perfectly, thanks. I have 3 Pixel 2 in family and all of them have the same problem with Android 10 and this solution works every time.